# Chess Code Split

Tags: java, performance, class, architecture

right now I am developing a chess game in java and have been writing the whole game in one java file without doing subclasses and I was hoping I could get some help with that

I want to separate the moves of all the pieces into a new file

can someone show me how to do that

This is the whole file below it is called ChessFrame,

I need help putting all the piece moves in a separate file called ChessMovement.java

I have tryed just taken out the movement but then that breaks everything I could really do with someone showing me

ChessFrame.java

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ChessFrame extends JFrame implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener {

    JLayeredPane layeredPane;
    JPanel chessBoard;
    JLabel chessPiece;
    int xAdjustment;
    int yAdjustment;
    int startX;
    int startY;
    int initialX;
    int initialY;
    JPanel panels;
    JLabel pieces;

    public ChessFrame() {
        Dimension boardSize = new Dimension(600, 600);

        //  Use a Layered Pane for this application
        layeredPane = new JLayeredPane();
        getContentPane().add(layeredPane);
        layeredPane.setPreferredSize(boardSize);
        layeredPane.addMouseListener(this);
        layeredPane.addMouseMotionListener(this);

        //Add a chess board to the Layered Pane
        chessBoard = new JPanel();
        layeredPane.add(chessBoard, JLayeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER);
        chessBoard.setLayout(new GridLayout(8, 8));
        chessBoard.setPreferredSize(boardSize);
        chessBoard.setBounds(0, 0, boardSize.width, boardSize.height);

        for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++) {
            JPanel square = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
            chessBoard.add(square);

            int row = (i / 8) % 2;
            if (row == 0) {
                square.setBackground(i % 2 == 0 ? Color.white : Color.gray);
            } else {
                square.setBackground(i % 2 == 0 ? Color.gray : Color.white);
            }
        }

        // Setting up the Initial Chess board.
        for (int i = 8; i < 16; i++) {
            pieces = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("WhitePawn.png"));
            panels = (JPanel) chessBoard.getComponent(i);
            panels.add(pieces);
        }
        pieces = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("WhiteRook.png"));
        panels = (JPanel) chessBoard.getComponent(0);
        panels.add(pieces);
        pieces = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("WhiteKnight.png"));
        panels = (JPanel) chessBoard.getComponent(1);
        panels.add(pieces);
        pieces = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("WhiteKnight.png"));
        panels = (JPanel) chessBoard.getComponent(6);
        panels.add(pieces);
        pieces = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("WhiteBishup.png"));
        panels = (JPanel) chessBoard.getComponent(2);
        panels.add(pieces);
        pieces = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("WhiteBishup.png"));
        panels = (JPanel) chessBoard.getComponent(5);
        panels.add(pieces);
        pieces = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("WhiteKing.png"));
        panels = (JPanel) chessBoard.getComponent(3);
        panels.add(pieces);
        pieces = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("WhiteQueen.png"));
        panels = (JPanel) chessBoard.getComponent(4);
        panels.add(pieces);
        pieces = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("WhiteRook.png"));
        panels = (JPanel) chessBoard.getComponent(7);
        panels.add(pieces);
        for (int i = 48; i < 56; i++) {
            pieces = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("BlackPawn.png"));
            panels = (JPanel) chessBoard.getComponent(i);
            panels.add(pieces);
        }
        pieces = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("BlackRook.png"));
        panels = (JPanel) chessBoard.getComponent(56);
        panels.add(pieces);
        pieces = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("BlackKnight.png"));
        panels = (JPanel) chessBoard.getComponent(57);
        panels.add(pieces);
        pieces = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("BlackKnight.png"));
        panels = (JPanel) chessBoard.getComponent(62);
        panels.add(pieces);
        pieces = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("BlackBishup.png"));
        panels = (JPanel) chessBoard.getComponent(58);
        panels.add(pieces);
        pieces = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("BlackBishup.png"));
        panels = (JPanel) chessBoard.getComponent(61);
        panels.add(pieces);
        pieces = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("BlackKing.png"));
        panels = (JPanel) chessBoard.getComponent(59);
        panels.add(pieces);
        pieces = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("BlackQueen.png"));
        panels = (JPanel) chessBoard.getComponent(60);
        panels.add(pieces);
        pieces = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("BlackRook.png"));
        panels = (JPanel) chessBoard.getComponent(63);
        panels.add(pieces);
    }

    private Boolean piecePresent(int x, int y) {
        Component c = chessBoard.findComponentAt(x, y);
        if (c instanceof JPanel) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    //Check if a piece is a Black piece.
    private Boolean checkWhiteOponent(int newX, int newY) {
        Boolean oponent;
        Component c1 = chessBoard.findComponentAt(newX, newY);
        JLabel awaitingPiece = (JLabel) c1;
        String tmp1 = awaitingPiece.getIcon().toString();
        if (((tmp1.contains("Black")))) {
            oponent = true;
        } else {
            oponent = false;
        }
        return oponent;
    }

    //Check if a piece is a White piece.

    private Boolean checkBlackOponent(int newX, int newY) {
        Boolean oponent;
        Component c1 = chessBoard.findComponentAt(newX, newY);
        JLabel awaitingPiece = (JLabel) c1;
        String tmp1 = awaitingPiece.getIcon().toString();
        if (((tmp1.contains("White")))) {
            oponent = true;
        } else {
            oponent = false;
        }
        return oponent;
    }

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        chessPiece = null;
        Component c = chessBoard.findComponentAt(e.getX(), e.getY());
        if (c instanceof JPanel) {
            return;
        }

        Point parentLocation = c.getParent().getLocation();
        xAdjustment = parentLocation.x - e.getX();
        yAdjustment = parentLocation.y - e.getY();
        chessPiece = (JLabel) c;
        initialX = e.getX();
        initialY = e.getY();
        startX = (e.getX() / 75);
        startY = (e.getY() / 75);
        chessPiece.setLocation(e.getX() + xAdjustment, e.getY() + yAdjustment);
        chessPiece.setSize(chessPiece.getWidth(), chessPiece.getHeight());
        layeredPane.add(chessPiece, JLayeredPane.DRAG_LAYER);
    }

    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent me) {
        if (chessPiece == null) {
            return;
        }
        chessPiece.setLocation(me.getX() + xAdjustment, me.getY() + yAdjustment);
    }

    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        if (chessPiece == null) {
            return;
        }

        chessPiece.setVisible(false);
        Boolean success = false;
        Component c = chessBoard.findComponentAt(e.getX(), e.getY());
        String tmp = chessPiece.getIcon().toString();
        String pieceName = tmp.substring(0, (tmp.length() - 4));
        Boolean validMove = false;

//Pawn Moves
//White Pawn
        if (pieceName.equals("WhitePawn")) {
            if (startY == 1) {
                if ((startX == (e.getX() / 75)) && ((((e.getY() / 75) - startY) == 1) || ((e.getY() / 75) - startY) == 2)) {
                    if ((((e.getY() / 75) - startY) == 2)) {
                        if ((!piecePresent(e.getX(), (e.getY()))) && (!piecePresent(e.getX(), (e.getY() + 75)))) {
                            validMove = true;
                        } else {
                            validMove = false;
                        }
                    } else {
                        if ((!piecePresent(e.getX(), (e.getY())))) {
                            validMove = true;
                        } else {
                            validMove = false;
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    validMove = false;
                }
            } else {
                int newY = e.getY() / 75;
                int newX = e.getX() / 75;
                if ((startX - 1 >= 0) || (startX + 1 <= 7)) {
                    if ((piecePresent(e.getX(), (e.getY()))) && ((((newX == (startX + 1) && (startX + 1 <= 7))) || ((newX == (startX - 1)) && (startX - 1 >= 0))))) {
                        if (checkWhiteOponent(e.getX(), e.getY())) {
                            validMove = true;
                            if (startY == 6) {
                                success = true;
                            }
                        } else {
                            validMove = false;
                        }
                    } else {
                        if (!piecePresent(e.getX(), (e.getY()))) {
                            if ((startX == (e.getX() / 75)) && ((e.getY() / 75) - startY) == 1) {
                                if (startY == 6) {
                                    success = true;
                                }
                                validMove = true;
                            } else {
                                validMove = false;
                            }
                        } else {
                            validMove = false;
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    validMove = false;
                }
            }
        }
//Black Pawn
        if (pieceName.equals("BlackPawn")) {
            if (startY == 6) {
                if ((startX == (e.getX() / 75)) && ((((e.getY() / 75) - startY) == -1) || ((e.getY() / 75) - startY) == -2)) {
                    if ((((e.getY() / 75) - startY) == -2)) {
                        if ((!piecePresent(e.getX(), (e.getY()))) && (!piecePresent(e.getX(), (e.getY() + 75)))) {
                            validMove = true;
                        } else {
                            validMove = false;
                        }
                    } else {
                        if ((!piecePresent(e.getX(), (e.getY())))) {
                            validMove = true;
                        } else {
                            validMove = false;
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    validMove = false;
                }
            } else {
                int newY = e.getY() / 75;
                int newX = e.getX() / 75;
                if ((startX - 1 >= 0) || (startX + 1 <= 7)) {
                    if ((piecePresent(e.getX(), (e.getY()))) && ((((newX == (startX + 1) && (startX + 1 <= 7))) || ((newX == (startX - 1)) && (startX - 1 >= 0))))) {
                        if (checkBlackOponent(e.getX(), e.getY())) {
                            validMove = true;
                            if (startY == 1) {
                                success = true;
                            }
                        } else {
                            validMove = false;
                        }
                    } else {
                        if (!piecePresent(e.getX(), (e.getY()))) {
                            if ((startX == (e.getX() / 75)) && ((e.getY() / 75) - startY) == -1) {
                                if (startY == 2) {
                                    success = true;
                                }
                                validMove = true;
                            } else {
                                validMove = false;
                            }
                        } else {
                            validMove = false;
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    validMove = false;
                }
            }
        }
        //End of Pawn Moves
        //Knight Moves
        //White Knight Code
        else if (pieceName.contains("WhiteKnight")) {

            // next we need to get the new coordinates for where the piece is being dropped.
            int newY = e.getY() / 75;
            int newX = e.getX() / 75;

            // We need to make sure that the piece is being put back on the board...if its not being on
            // the board why would we want to check anything else!
            if (((newX < 0) || (newX > 7)) || ((newY < 0) || (newY > 7))) {
                validMove = false;
            } else {

                if (((newX == startX + 1) && (newY == startY + 2)) || ((newX == startX - 1) && (newY == startY + 2)) || ((newX == startX + 2) && (newY == startY + 1)) || ((newX == startX - 2) && (newY == startY + 1)) || ((newX == startX + 1) && (newY == startY - 2)) || ((newX == startX - 1) && (newY == startY - 2)) || ((newX == startX + 2) && (newY == startY - 1)) || ((newX == startX - 2) && (newY == startY - 1))) {
                    validMove = true;

                    if (piecePresent(e.getX(), (e.getY()))) {
                        if (pieceName.contains("White")) {
                            if (checkWhiteOponent(e.getX(), e.getY())) {
                                validMove = true;
                            } else {
                                validMove = false;
                            }
                        } else {
                            if (checkBlackOponent(e.getX(), e.getY())) {
                                validMove = true;
                            } else {
                                validMove = false;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    validMove = false;
                }
            }
        } //Black Knight Code
        else if (pieceName.contains("BlackKnight")) {

                    // next we need to get the new coordinates for where the piece is being dropped.
            int newY = e.getY() / 75;
            int newX = e.getX() / 75;

                    // We need to make sure that the piece is being put back on the board...if its not being on
                    // the board why would we want to check anything else!
            if (((newX < 0) || (newX > 7)) || ((newY < 0) || (newY > 7))) {
                validMove = false;
            } else {
                if (((newX == startX + 1) && (newY == startY + 2)) || ((newX == startX - 1) && (newY == startY + 2)) || ((newX == startX + 2) && (newY == startY + 1)) || ((newX == startX - 2) && (newY == startY + 1)) || ((newX == startX + 1) && (newY == startY - 2)) || ((newX == startX - 1) && (newY == startY - 2)) || ((newX == startX + 2) && (newY == startY - 1)) || ((newX == startX - 2) && (newY == startY - 1))) {
                    validMove = true;

                    if (piecePresent(e.getX(), (e.getY()))) {
                        if (pieceName.contains("Black")) {
                            if (checkBlackOponent(e.getX(), e.getY())) {
                                validMove = true;
                            } else {
                                validMove = false;
                            }
                        } else {
                            if (checkWhiteOponent(e.getX(), e.getY())) {
                                validMove = true;
                            } else {
                                validMove = false;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    validMove = false;
                }
            }
        }
        //End of Knight Code
        //Bishop Code
        //White Bishup
        else if (pieceName.contains("WhiteBishup")) {
            int newY = e.getY() / 75;
            int newX = e.getX() / 75;
            boolean inTheWay = false;
            int distance = Math.abs(startX - newX);
            if (((newX < 0) || (newX > 7)) || ((newY < 0) || (newY > 7))) {
                validMove = false;
            } else {
                validMove = true;
                if (Math.abs(startX - newX) == Math.abs(startY - newY)) {
                    if ((startX - newX < 0) && (startY - newY < 0)) {
                        for (int i = 0; i < distance; i++) {
                            if (piecePresent((initialX + (i * 75)), (initialY + (i * 75)))) {
                                inTheWay = true;
                            }
                        }
                    } else if ((startX - newX < 0) && (startY - newY > 0)) {
                        for (int i = 0; i < distance; i++) {
                            if (piecePresent((initialX + (i * 75)), (initialY - (i * 75)))) {
                                inTheWay = true;
                            }
                        }
                    } else if ((startX - newX > 0) && (startY - newY > 0)) {
                        for (int i = 0; i < distance; i++) {
                            if (piecePresent((initialX - (i * 75)), (initialY - (i * 75)))) {
                                inTheWay = true;
                            }
                        }
                    } else if ((startX - newX > 0) && (startY - newY < 0)) {
                        for (int i = 0; i < distance; i++) {
                            if (piecePresent((initialX - (i * 75)), (initialY + (i * 75)))) {
                                inTheWay = true;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if (inTheWay) {
                        validMove = false;
                    } else {
                        if (piecePresent(e.getX(), (e.getY()))) {
                            if (pieceName.contains("White")) {
                                if (checkWhiteOponent(e.getX(), e.getY())) {
                                    validMove = true;
                                } else {
                                    validMove = false;
                                }
                            } else {
                                if (checkBlackOponent(e.getX(), e.getY())) {
                                    validMove = true;
                                } else {
                                    validMove = false;
                                }
                            }
                        } else {
                            validMove = true;
                        }
                    }
                } else { // the move that is being tried is not a diagonal move...
                    validMove = false;
                }
            }
        } //Black Bishup
        else if (pieceName.contains("BlackBishup")) {
            int newY = e.getY() / 75;
            int newX = e.getX() / 75;
            boolean inTheWay = false;
            int distance = Math.abs(startX - newX);
            if (((newX < 0) || (newX > 7)) || ((newY < 0) || (newY > 7))) {
                validMove = false;
            } else {
                validMove = true;
                if (Math.abs(startX - newX) == Math.abs(startY - newY)) {
                    if ((startX - newX < 0) && (startY - newY < 0)) {
                        for (int i = 0; i < distance; i++) {
                            if (piecePresent((initialX + (i * 75)), (initialY + (i * 75)))) {
                                inTheWay = true;
                            }
                        }
                    } else if ((startX - newX < 0) && (startY - newY > 0)) {
                        for (int i = 0; i < distance; i++) {
                            if (piecePresent((initialX + (i * 75)), (initialY - (i * 75)))) {
                                inTheWay = true;
                            }
                        }
                    } else if ((startX - newX > 0) && (startY - newY > 0)) {
                        for (int i = 0; i < distance; i++) {
                            if (piecePresent((initialX - (i * 75)), (initialY - (i * 75)))) {
                                inTheWay = true;
                            }
                        }
                    } else if ((startX - newX > 0) && (startY - newY < 0)) {
                        for (int i = 0; i < distance; i++) {
                            if (piecePresent((initialX - (i * 75)), (initialY + (i * 75)))) {
                                inTheWay = true;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if (inTheWay) {
                        validMove = false;
                    } else {
                        if (piecePresent(e.getX(), (e.getY()))) {
                            if (pieceName.contains("Black")) {
                                if (checkBlackOponent(e.getX(), e.getY())) {
                                    validMove = true;
                                } else {
                                    validMove = false;
                                }
                            } else {
                                if (checkWhiteOponent(e.getX(), e.getY())) {
                                    validMove = true;
                                } else {
                                    validMove = false;
                                }
                            }
                        } else {
                            validMove = true;
                        }
                    }
                } else { // the move that is being tried is not a diagonal move...
                    validMove = false;
                }
            }
        }
        //End of Bishup Code


//Changes to new pawn Piece and Validates Move

    if(!validMove){
        int location=0;
        if(startY ==0){
            location = startX;
        }
        else{
            location  = (startY*8)+startX;
        }
        String pieceLocation = pieceName+".png";
        pieces = new JLabel( new ImageIcon(pieceLocation) );
        panels = (JPanel)chessBoard.getComponent(location);
        panels.add(pieces);
    }
    else{
        if(success){

            if (c instanceof JLabel){
                Container parent = c.getParent();
                parent.remove(0);

                String promoteTo;
                do {
                    promoteTo = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                        "Promote Pawn to :", "Pawn Promotion",
                        JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null,
                        new String[]{"Queen", "Bishup", "Knight", "Rook"}, "Queen");
                } while (promoteTo == null);
                String newPiece = null;
                int location = 0;
                if (pieceName.contains("White"))
                {
                    location = 56 + (e.getX()/75);
                    newPiece = "White"+promoteTo;
                }
                else
                {
                    location =  (e.getX()/75);
                    newPiece = "Black"+promoteTo;
                }

                pieces = new JLabel( new ImageIcon(newPiece+".png") );
                parent = (JPanel)chessBoard.getComponent(location);
                parent.add(pieces);
                validate();
                repaint();
            }
        }
        else{
            if (c instanceof JLabel){
                Container parent = c.getParent();
                parent.remove(0);
                parent.add( chessPiece );
            }
            else {
                Container parent = (Container)c;
                parent.add( chessPiece );
            }
            chessPiece.setVisible(true);
        }
    }
    }

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

    }

    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {

    }

    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new ChessFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setResizable(true);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Any help would be great the code currently has no errors but I dont want to go any further til I have it separated out

thanks for any help

Comment: This has also been posted at Code Review: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/68853/chess-architecture **and is not a really good fit for either site**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a Piece class, which has subclasses for all the piece types.  Then create a [Factory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern)PieceFactory.getPiece(pieceName, x pos, y pos, chessboard) to get those pieces, and implement a move() method on it which takes your new position, and does all the validation.  This leaves your UI logic for rendering the moves here, but pushes the move logic down into the piece objects.

You will probably change this later to create a ChessBoard object, which will allow you to get a piece by it's x,y coordinates, and thus not know the piece's name.  chessBoard.getPiece(x,y).move(newX, newY);  That will allow you validate moves, plus deal with captures etc, calling back to the board to remove opposing pieces.

Answer (score 1):

You mixed game-logic with GUI elements. You should use the concept of [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller). To refractor your program at this state is a question too unspecific.

Comment: i have already reviewed that concept and have been going around in circles this is not useful at all

Comment: @Jamiex304 You have been posting several question related to this chess game recently. This will not end. You can't develop an application by posting a few hundred lines of code, and then hoping for others to aid you in adding new features. Refactor the code. And in this case this means: Rewrite it. From scratch. You can't improve your programming skills by maintaining a [Lava Flow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lava_flow_%28programming%29)

Comment: @Jamiex304 if you do not understand the concept of MVC, then try asking specific questions to the topic you do not understand. We cannot help you if we do not know, what you do not understand.